# PyTorch Trainer Class

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm working with a few different generative models (DDPMs, VAEs, GANs).  Each requires a different training loop, but I still find myself rewriting some similar training steps when defining training scripts for each model.

I had an idea to write a parent PyTorch `trainer` class.  Then each model could subclass this `trainer class`, and each model could have it's own specific `train()` method.

Has anyone done this before?  What are some potential pitfalls of this idea?  Do you think its possible to build a parent general class that has useful functionality but that could still be referenced for completely different training procedures, say a GAN vs a VAE?

I currently have a very basic trainer function that works alright for DDPMs and VAEs, but can't handle the GAN training format.

```
def train_model(
    train_loader,
    model_class, 
    model_parameters,
    device,
    loss_function,
    valid_loader=None,
    preprocess_inputs=None,
    postprocess_outputs=None,
    additional_loss_steps=False,
    epochs=50, 
    lr=0.0001,
    save_dir='./saved_model'
):
    
    model = model_class(*model_parameters).to(device)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
        os.makedirs(save_dir)

    csv_file = os.path.join(save_dir, 'loss.csv')
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Epoch', 'Loss'])

        model.train()

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            train_loss = 0
            for i, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                if preprocess_inputs:
                    batch = preprocess_inputs(batch)
                if isinstance(batch, tuple) or isinstance(batch, list):
                    batch = tuple([item.to(device) for item in batch])
                    outputs = model(*batch)
                else:
                    batch = batch.to(device)
                    outputs = model(batch)
                # Postprocess the outputs if needed
                if postprocess_outputs:
                    outputs = postprocess_outputs(outputs)
                if additional_loss_steps:
                    loss = loss_function(outputs, batch, model)
                else:
                    loss = loss_function(*batch, *outputs)
                loss.backward()
                train_loss += loss.item()
                optimizer.step()

            avg_train_loss = train_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)
            if valid_loader:
                model.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode
                valid_loss = 0
                with torch.no_grad():  # Don't calculate gradients
                    for i, batch in enumerate(valid_loader):
                        if preprocess_inputs:
                            batch = preprocess_inputs(batch)
                        if isinstance(batch, tuple) or isinstance(batch, list):
                            batch = tuple([item.to(device) for item in batch])
                            outputs = model(*batch)
                        else:
                            batch = batch.to(device)
                            outputs = model(batch)
                        # Postprocess the outputs if needed
                        if postprocess_outputs:
                            outputs = postprocess_outputs(outputs)
                        if additional_loss_steps:
                            loss = loss_function(outputs, batch, model)
                        else:
                            loss = loss_function(*batch, *outputs)
                        valid_loss += loss.item()
                        
                avg_valid_loss = valid_loss / len(valid_loader.dataset)
                
                print(f'Epoch {epoch}, Train Loss: {avg_train_loss:.4f}, Valid Loss: {avg_valid_loss:.4f}')
                writer.writerow([epoch, avg_train_loss, avg_valid_loss])  # Save train and valid loss
            else:
                print(f'Epoch {epoch}, Train Loss: {avg_train_loss:.4f}')
                writer.writerow([epoch, avg_train_loss])

    model_file = os.path.join(save_dir, 'model.pth')
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_file)

    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pytorch-lightning` library. It has already what you need. https://lightning.ai/

Comment: I'll check that out, thank you! (By the way, I upvoted but don't have enough rep)